# How to launch browser in full screen (maximised)- playwright c#

Tags: c#, playwright

Im attempting to launch a browser using playwright/C# with the browser maximised.

Ive successfully managed to use SetViewPortSizeAsync to set the size of the browser, however id like to have the browser to be set to the maximum size, irrespectiv of where the tests are run.

below is some basic code that I managed to set the browser size with

```
public async Task pageLaunchTest()
{
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();

await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
{
//Args = new string[] { "--start-maximized" },
Headless = false,
});

var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.SetViewportSizeAsync(500, 500);
    
await page.GotoAsync("https://playwright.dev/");
var pageTitle = await page.TitleAsync();
Assert.Equal ("Fast and reliable end-to-end testing for modern web apps | Playwright", 
pageTitle);
```

Unfortunately I was not able to maximise the browser using the setviewportsize method.
Note that on line 3 I also tried passing an argument  '--start-maximised' which others seem to have been successful with but this did not work for me so have commented this out temporarily.
Would appreciate any advice on how to effectively maximise the window before page navigation

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```cs
using Microsoft.Playwright;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
        await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();

        //In your Browser context set viewport size to null so that it will set to maximum size as per your screen size. 
        var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(new BrowserNewContextOptions
        {
            // Set viewport size to null for maximum size
            ViewportSize = null 
        });

        var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
        
        // Navigate to your desired URL
        await page.GotoAsync("https://example.com");

        // You can also set a specific size if needed
        await page.SetViewportSizeAsync(1280, 720);

        // Perform your tests...

        await context.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```